# Running Python - 500 Internal Service Error

Tags: python, apache, nearlyfreespeech

I have the following code (test.cgi):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

print "Hello World!"
```

The file is CHMOD 777 and so is the directory it is in.

I am getting the following error log

```
[Sun Apr 12 02:24:46.395628 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 3574:tid 34479148032] [client 172.17.240.2:19716] AH01215: env: python\r: : /fs5a/cheerupper/public/scripts/test.cgi
[Sun Apr 12 02:24:46.396715 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 3574:tid 34479148032] [client 172.17.240.2:19716] AH01215: No such file or directory: /fs5a/cheerupper/public/scripts/test.cgi
[Sun Apr 12 02:24:46.397453 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 3574:tid 34479148032] [client 172.17.240.2:19716] End of script output before headers: test.cgi
```

I am getting a 500 Internal Service Error when I try to run in a browser. I can run when SSHing into the server by the command line. I have tried on Namecheap servers and am now trying on NearlyFreeSpeech.net to the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your file is saved with Windows newlines. Your editor should have an option to change it to Unix newlines, which your server expects.

Comment: I tried using sed to do this: `sed 's/^M$//' test.cgi > test.cgi` which did nothing.

Comment: I figured out how to convert. Such a small obscure problem to cause all this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

short and simple CGI program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

print "Hello World!"
```